# Print jQuery variables to PHP

Tags: php, jquery

On same php file I save two variables with this script and like to print both with php

```
$('#table tbody').on( 'click', 'td', function () {
        var row = $(this).parent().find('td').html().trim();
        var column = $('#table thead tr th').eq($(this).index()).html().trim();
});
```

My php code contains this:

```
if(isset($_POST['row'])){
    echo $_POST['row'];
}
```

But not print nothing. What's the problem on code

Comment: jQuery is client side, PHP is server side. How are you sending your jQuery var back to the server?

Comment: [What are the differences between server-side and client-side programming?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/171203/what-are-the-differences-between-server-side-and-client-side-programming)

Comment: @sean with jquery detect certain values on table (name column and the first row)

Answer (score 0):

**First of all you need to send that jQuery Variable to your PHP file! If you want this to be done in the same web page without reloading, then in this case I would use AJAX, in order to use $_POST to retrieve the jQuery value:**

jQuery Code:

```
$('#table tbody').on( 'click', 'td', function () {
            var row = $(this).parent().find('td').html().trim();
            var column = $('#table thead tr th').eq($(this).index()).html().trim();
            $.ajax({
                url: "//url to your php file//",
                data: {ajaxROW: row},
                type: "POST",
                async: false,
            }).done(function() {
                alert("Done");
            });   
        });
```

PHP Code:

```
if(isset($_POST['ajaxROW'])){
      echo $_POST['ajaxROW'];
}
```

Comment: I put this but can run. I only update with **url: "index.php"**

Comment: If I understand right, you only use your index.php file for everything, said this, I can think of two solutions:

1 - in the $.ajax request, in the url field, put "/index.php"
2 - create another PHP file, just with the PHP code that you need to run, and put the name of the file in the url field on the ajax request.

Comment: Put url: **"/index.php",** too but not see results

Comment: Weird, this could mean that the variable is empty when sending it. Just to check something of the list, delete the isset from your PHP code, and just run the 'echo'